# A question about transient voltage supression

Tags: usb, tvs, static

I am a programmer that often ends up testing electronics while testing my code.  I've seen the following happen a few times, and when I asked my EE about it the other day he just kinda shrugged and walked away... So I am asking my question here.

I have a battery powered microcontroller in a cylindrical aluminum housing. The elecronics have no connection to the chassis at all. The housing sits on a plastic saddle, and is mounted to the frame using insulated u-bolts. While connected to a computer via USB, I have witnessed a USB disconnection from the PC when someone touches the frame.  It's very rare, and seems like a static discharge because it only happens once. How would a static discharge on the frame get to electronics that have no connection to the frame at all?

[image: System]

[image: USB Connection]

Comment: There is a connection--those insulated u-bolts and plastic saddle. ESD events involve high voltages that may be able to make it through those. There'll also be a bit of radiated noise when it happens, that could be picked up by PCB traces acting like antennas.